# How to hook in to WooCommerce Related Products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

Have done some searching, but all the solutions to this problem relate to excluding categories and/or tags.

How do I hook into woocommerce_get_related_products so I can exclude the following:

product_cat = sold

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Reference link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109455/woocommerce-exclude-specific-category-products-from-related-products?rq=1

Comment: @Patel - thanks, but this only relates to WP categories and not product_cat